# mod_rewrite use variable's numeric position in url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I apologize if the title isn't quite clear as I am new to mod_rewrite and I am not sure how to phrase the question correctly.

I want to rewrite a fancy url such as **http://www.url.com/module/subdirectory/another_subdirectory/page** to **http://www.url.com/d_1=module&d_2=subdirectory&d_3=another_subdirectory&page=page**. The number of subdirectories varies so the parameter d_* can be dynamic (trying to keep it between d_1 and d_9 though). The fancy url can also have its own query string and it needs to be rewritten to occur after the page parameter.

I did a read through of Apache's mod_rewrite and regex documentation and spent some time searching on Google and Stackoverflow for an answer to this but could not find anything for this specific problem. Any help on this problem from someone much more knowledgable would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Its much easier to do this logic in an application e.g. php. I assume you have a good reason to do attempt this in Apache

Comment: I'm running with namespaces in a custom PHP CMS. Each page is a class in its own file. The url **?d_1=module&d_2=subdirectory&d_3=another_subdirectory&page=page** tells the CMS to instantiate the \Module\Subdirectory\AnotherSubdirectory\Page class. I wanted to make the fancy urls hide the ugliness going on. Is there another method to approach this with that I am not seeing?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below in the .htacess in the root directory, though you need to finish the cases up to 9.

I am also assuming that your CMS application is index.php. If not replace with correct .php file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

#one subdir
RewriteRule ^module/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?d_1=module&d_2=$1&page=$2 [QSA,L,NC]
#two subdir
RewriteRule ^module/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?d_1=module&d_2=$1&d_3=$2&page=$3 [QSA,L,NC]
#three subdir
RewriteRule ^module/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?d_1=module&d_2=$1&d_3=$2&d_4=$3&page=$4 [QSA,L,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

Alteration of Ulrich's code that doesn't need as much repeating, by making the subdir-parts optional. The last part always maps to `page`:

```
RewriteRule ^(module)/(?:([^/]+)/)?(?:([^/]+)/)?(?:([^/]+)/)?(?:([^/]+)/)?(?:([^/]+)/)?(?:([^/]+)/)?(?:([^/]+)/)?(?:([^/]+)/)?([^/]+)$ index.php?d_1=$1&d_2=$2&d_3=$3&d_4=$4&d_5=$5&d_6=$6&d_7=$7&d_8=$8&page=$9 [QSA,L,NC]
```

Though I would prefer to use some php code for this.

```
$dirs = expode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
array_shift($dirs);//remove first empty string.
$page = array_pop($dirs);//get last part of the url.
```