# .htaccess rewrite urls with many GET s, to dir style like: /page/subpage/subpage1/subpage2/ and so on

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, get

right now I am using these on a .htaccess file

```
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)\.html$ index.php?lng=$1&page=$2&subpage=$3&subpage1=$4 [L]
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)/(.*)\.html$ index.php?lng=$1&page=$2&subpage=$3 [L]
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)\.html$ index.php?lng=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule (.*)\.html$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule index\.html$ index.php [L]
```

and work fine.

If I want to add another subpage then I must enter a new RewriteRule which will include all gets. For example if i want to add another subpage to the previous code, i should enter:

```
 RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)\.html$ index.php?lng=$1&page=$2&subpage=$3&subpage1=$4&subpage1=$5 [L]
```

**But how can I make it to be more simple and generic to handle all gets?**

Note: I don't care about GET names (page, subpage1 ....)

*Edit: I want to be able to get the query string but i do not care about the names (keys): page , subpage, subpage1 e.t.c.*

Comment: I do not understand the `I don't care about GET names` part. If it is Ok to redirect all pages to index.php without query string, you could just write `RewriteRule (.*) index.php [L]`?

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8983252/mod-rewrite-use-variables-numeric-position-in-url/9002714#9002714 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9091621/handliing-blank-values-in-url-with-url-rewritting/9096424#9096424

Answer (score 0):

You can use only one (looooong) rule, but it'll be ugly, be ready...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(/([^/]+))?(/([^/]+))?(/([^/]+))?(/([^/]+))?\.html$  index.php?p1=$1&p2=$3&p3=$5&p4=$7&p5=$9 [L]
```

The trick here is use the pattern `(/([^/]+))?` and get impair params (1,3,5...)

For example, with url `www.domain.com/a/b/c.html`, you'll get :

- $1 = a
- $2 = /b
- $3 = b
- $4 = /c
- $5 = c
- $6~$9 = null